# How To Make Jquery Submenu Stay Visible After It Is Clicked?

Tags: jquery

I have read similar posts but as I am not very good with jquery I need more specific help with my menu.

```
<div id="nav"><!--// START NAV //-->
    <dl id="nav">
        <dt class="nav"><b>ONE</b></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/A">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="/B">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="/C">C</a></li>

            </ul>
        </dd>
        <dt class="nav"><b>TWO</b></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="/D">D</a></li>
                <li><a href="/E">E</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/F">F</a></li>
                </ul>
        </dd>

    </dl>
        </div><!--// END NAV //-->
```

Here is the JS I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#nav")) {
        $("#nav dd").hide();
        $("#nav dt.nav b").click(function() {
            if(this.className.indexOf("clicked") != -1) {
                $(this).parent().next().slideUp(200);
                $(this).removeClass("clicked");
            }
            else {
                $("#nav dt.nav b").removeClass();
                $(this).addClass("clicked");
                $("#nav dd:visible").slideUp(200);
                $(this).parent().next().slideDown(500);
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: "How To Make Jquery Submenu Stay Visible After It Is Clicked?"

Answer (score 1):

The menu hides due to pagerefresh. You can avoid it, by adding click handler, that returns false. Add this code to your `ready` handler:

```
$("#nav dd ul a").click(function(){
    return false;
})
```

Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gorsky/SUjNR/).

**Update:**

You can store selected url in cookies. Here is [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/gorsky/SUjNR/13/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#nav")) {
        $("#nav dd").hide();
        $("#nav dt.nav b").click(function() {
            if (this.className.indexOf("clicked") != -1) {
                $(this).parent().next().slideUp(200);
                $(this).removeClass("clicked");
            }
            else {
                $("#nav dt.nav b").removeClass();
                $(this).addClass("clicked");
                $("#nav dd:visible").slideUp(200);
                $(this).parent().next().slideDown(500);
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    $("#nav dd ul a").click(function() {
        $.cookie('link_href', $(this).attr('href'));
    });

    alert($.cookie('link_href'));

    var selector = 'a[href="'+ $.cookie('link_href') +'"]';
    $(selector).parents('dd').prev().find('b').click();
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Gor, But now the links <a href> do not click/open pages?

Comment: If you want not to collapse menu on item clicks, just maintain state on server side or load content via ajax (without page refresh) or save state on cookies/local storage.

Comment: I do not know how to achieve any of the three suggestions.

Comment: I was hoping that a little bit of code like what you posted would do it?

Comment: i'm going to post sample tomorrow

Comment: Thanks for edit, almost missed it. Now the <dd> content does not stay visible when clicked/on selected page?

Comment: Boo-hoo, totally stuck, perhaps someone can suggest a ready to go jquery collapsable menu of which it's child <li> can be made to stay visible when cliked?