# Making id link visible - Preventing the default event when the anchor is clicked.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

a really simple question but I couldn't think of the "right" words to search on google. My problem is I want to make the link 'History' still visible after I click it. I don't want the page to go down to div, but just change content. I know I'll need jquery to hide/switch content, but I'm stuck at the link part.

```
#goals{
display             : none;
}

#history{
display             : block;
}
```

---

```
<p ><a id="History" href="#history"> <b>History</b> </a></p>
<p ><a id="Goals" href="#goals"> <b>Goals</b> </a></p>

<div id="history">
<p> blah blah blah </p>
</div>

<div id="goals">
<p> blah blah blah </p>
</div>
```

---

```
$("#Goals").click(function(){
        $("#history).hide();
        $("#goals").show();
})
```

Comment: You'll need JavaScript in order to cancel the default action of the link. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089834/how-to-make-jquery-submenu-stay-visible-after-it-is-clicked

But the solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Post your full code. How is `#history` being hidden in the first place?

Comment: The full code has too much content so i'm just showing the outline, but I'm still learning jquery so I don't have a "good" solution figured out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `preventDefault()` method on the event argument passed to your handler.  For example:

```
<a id="historyLink" href="#">History</a>
```

...and...

```
$('#historyLink').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // block the default action
   // do something
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured out the switch content but I was still stuck with href problem. Totally forgot you can just put '#' to keep it as link.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need CSS, you can do it all with jQuery:

HTML

```
<p ><a id="History" href="#history"> <b>History</b> </a></p>
<p ><a id="Goals" href="#goals"> <b>Goals</b> </a></p>

<div id="history">
<p> history blah blah blah </p>
</div>

<div id="goals">
<p> goals blah blah blah </p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#goals").hide();

$("#Goals").click(function(){
    $("#history").hide();
    $("#goals").show();
});

$("#History").click(function(){
    $("#goals").hide();
    $("#history").show();
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vzNN/) to tie it all together.

Comment: Yep I did that except '$("#goals").hide();'. It seems to work now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason you page is moving is because that is the default action for the click event on an anchor. 
What you need to do is make sure that the default action does not happen (which is what is responsible for the 'movement' on your page.
I would suggest the following:

```
<!-- you don't need to link it to the actual id, since you are toggling the visibility using jQuery -->
<a id="historyLink" href="#">History</a>
```

Then, as far as jQuery is concerned:

```
$('#historyLink').click(function(event){
    //prevent the page from scrolling
    event.preventDefault();
    //possibly hide the other div if it is visible
    $('#theotherdiv').hide();
    //show the div
    $('#historyLink').show();
});
```